# Limit cursor-based node traversal to outgoing edges

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to adapt Max de Marzi's [Parallel K-Hop Counts example](https://maxdemarzi.com/2019/07/25/parallel-k-hop-counts/) to a problem on a directed graph. Using relationship and node cursors

```java
RelationshipTraversalCursor relsCursor = cursors.allocateRelationshipTraversalCursor();
NodeCursor nodeCursor = cursors.allocateNodeCursor();

read.singleNode(startingNode.getId(), nodeCursor);
nodeCursor.next();

nodeCursor.allRelationships(relsCursor);
```

how would I limit the iteration over the relationships `while (relsCursor.next()) {...}` to the outgoing edges?

So far I achieved this using the `Iterable<Relationship> getRelationships(Direction var1)` function of the `org.neo4j.graphdb.Node`, but since my intuition of the internal Neo4j Java API is limited, I would like to compare relative performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a helpful snippet from a relevant [neo4j test method](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/4.2/community/community-it/kernel-it/src/test/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/newapi/RelationshipTestSupport.java#L230) that shows how to determine the direction of the cursor's current relationship:

```
private static String computeKey( ..., RelationshipTraversalCursor r )
{
    Direction d;
    if ( r.sourceNodeReference() == r.targetNodeReference() )
    {
        d = Direction.BOTH;
    }
    else if ( r.sourceNodeReference() == r.originNodeReference() )
    {
        d = Direction.OUTGOING;
    }
    else
    {
        d = Direction.INCOMING;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

So, something like this should work for you:

```
while (relsCursor.next()) {
    if (relsCursor.sourceNodeReference() == relsCursor.originNodeReference()) {
        // Do OUTGOING relationship processing
    }
}
```